# What is the best romanization of ח?

Tags: orthography, hebrew, romanization

I have seen ח represented as ch, gh, kh, H (capitalized), x, h with diacritics, etc.
Personally, I like using x, because it is a single letter and does not require special diacritic markings, etc ...

Is there an official standard of romanization for Hebrew?

Comment: There is a similar issue with כ khaf.

Comment: @Henry then you also need to get into what form of Hebrew you care about transcribing, and therefore whether you care about maintaining a distinction between chaf & khet

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[There are several different standards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romanization_of_Hebrew#Standards), so which one you want to use will depend on your goal. For the purpose of conversing on the internet, for example, most people use *ch*; for linguistic purposes, *ḥ* is standard; for just using Hebrew words in an English context, just plain *h* is common.

Anecdotally, I would expect most linguists to understand *x* (since it's a standard IPA symbol), but most English-speakers seeing "Xanukkah" would pronounce it with `/z/` (since that's the standard pronunciation of word-initial X in English); likewise, they'd say "Noax" with `/ks/`.